# Confusion with Prototype in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

### 1.

I read Douglas Crockford's JavaScript Good Parts book. In the book, `method` is added to `Function.prototype`

a.

```
Function.prototype.method = function() {}

Function.prototype.method === Function.method; // true
```

b.

```
function MyClass() {}

MyClass.prototype.method = function() {}

MyClass.prototype.method == MyClass.method // false
```

infact `MyClass.method` is undefined.

Why is it true in step a and false in step b?

### 2.

please explain the following:

```
Object instanceof Function    // true
Function instanceof Object    // true
Object instanceof Object      // true
Function instanceof Function  // true
```

It is very confusing. please explain in simple words.

Comment: Thanks for asking, I couldn't get all aspects in one place in my head to make a cohesive question. Up and Fav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1a.**

```
01 Function.prototype.method = function foo() {}
02 Function.prototype.method === Function.method; // true
```

This is the addition of a property to the object pointed to by the  `prototype` property of the built-in `Function` function-object.

`Function` is a **built-in** function-object instance named "Function".
`Function` is therefore an object because functions are objects.
Because `Function` is a function, it has a `prototype` property. In this case, it is another function-object.

Line 1 above adds a property named `method` to `Function.prototype` pointing it to the function-object `foo` (named for clarity).

Line 2 performs a test for reference equality between `Function.prototype.method` (created in line 1) and the result of attempting to get the value associated with the property `method` on the built-in `Function` function-object. Property resolution in JavaScript is performed by searching the chain of objects linked by the prototype-chain.

So in line 2 `Function.prototype.method` finds the property immediately as the `method` property is located directly on `Function.prototype`.

Also on line 2, `Function.method` is *not* found immediately on `Function`; the search then continues by looking at what is pointed at by the `Function.__proto__` property (this is known as the prototype chain). The `__proto__` reference in JavaScript automatically points to the `prototype` property of the function that created it. In this case, because we are at the top of the prototype chain (**this is the top-most function**!), we have the unusual situation where the built-in `Function` "created itself" (in reality `Function` was created by the runtime itself, outside of userland code), meaning that both the `prototype` and `__proto__` properties - in this instance - point to the same object.

So the search for `method` follows the `__proto__` link, finds the same object pointed to by `Function.prototype`, and finds a property `method` there. Hence:

```
02 Function.prototype.method === Function.method; // true
```

**1b.**

```
01 function MyClass() {}    
02 MyClass.prototype.method = function foo() {} // Named for clarity.
03 MyClass.prototype.method == MyClass.method // false 
04 // infact MyClass.method is undefined.
```

This is normal userland code and we do not have the same problem of having to find the prototype for the *top-most* `Function` object as in 1a.

As soon as it is declared (line 1 above), `MyClass` gets a `prototype` property like every function, pointing to an empty object instance.

Line 2 adds a property `method` to this empty object instance and points it to a function `foo`.

Line 3 tests for reference equality between `foo` and the result of looking for a property `method` on `MyClass`. As before, to find `method` on `MyClass` a search is performed. It does not exist directly on `MyClass`, so the object located on the property `__proto__` is checked for a property named method (again, this is the prototype chain being traversed). In this case, just like 1a (and as for every object in JavaScript), the `__proto__` points to the `prototype` property of the function that created the object. Function-object `MyClass` was created by the built-in `Function` function-object, thus `MyClass.__proto__` points to `Function.prototype` (note, not `MyClass.prototype`). It finds nothing there and continues the search up the prototype chain. It ultimately fails to find a property called `method`, so returns `undefined`.

Hence:

```
MyClass.prototype.method == MyClass.method // false
```

**2.**

```
Object instanceof Function    // true
```

Object is a built-in constructor function-object for creating objects. Hence it is a function.

---

```
Function instanceof Object    // true
```

`instanceof` is an operator that returns true if the **prototype property** of the RHS object resides on the prototype chain of the LHS. The prototype chain of Function is:

```
Function.__proto__ -> Function.prototype
Function.prototype -> function f() {} // An ordinary function, named for clarity
f.__proto__ -> {} // An ordinary object. Let's call it 'o'.
```

So at the top of the prototype chain for functions, in order to avoid a circular loop, the prototype of the `Object` constructor function is used as `f.__proto__` (I call it `f` here for clarity). Hence:

```
Function instanceof Object    // true
```

---

```
Object instanceof Object      // true
```

For this to be true `Object.prototype` must be on the prototype chain of `Object`.

```
Object.__proto__ -> Function.prototype 
Function.prototype.__proto__ -> {} // This is 'o' from above.
```

So `Function.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype`, hence:

```
Object instanceof Object      // true
```

---

```
Function instanceof Function  // true
```

This is true for the same explanation as 1a.

Answer (score 4):

**1.**

a) You have just extended the Function built in object and now every instance of Function has that property attached, including the Function built in instance.

b) You have just extended MyClass with method and now every instance of MyClass has that method attached. *However*, MyClass is not an instance of MyClass and as a result that method is not present.

**2.**

These are standard built-in objects in the language. They are instances which can return an instance. With regards to Object, its prototype is shared with everything because everything derives from Object - it is best in general to avoid changing its prototype.

So that is why it seems that Function is an instance of Object. Everything is. Every instance derives from Function, so the Object instance is also an instance of Function. And that is the reverse.

There is a whole set of other fundamental objects, Object will not be an instance of Number for example, but Number is an instance of both Object and Function.

More on this list can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects

Shown below is only a small subset of these objects as the list contained some objects which are more than likely not of interest (such as URIError).

- Object
- Function
- Boolean
- Symbol
- Error
- Number
- Math
- Date
- String
- RegExp
- Array
- JSON
- Promise

Comment: "You have just extended the Function built in object and now every instance of Function has that property attached, including the Function built in instance." Although this is slightly counterintuitive because we rarely deal with the top of the prototype chain.

Comment: @BenAston - That is a good point. It is avoided for a reason :D Also, there is no way to tell how Function is constructed internally because that is actually up to the browser. In general it probably just returns a new instance each time along with several other behind the scenes actions but getting to that level of analysis would be very difficult.